# TYPO3: Flag to add teaser images directly

Tags: permissions, upload, resources, typo3

I'm adding a user group as writer currently, but I'm can't add new images directly as teaser pictures in the resources tab. I can access the resources tab but doesn't see the "upload new picture" button.

Does anybody know, which flags I need to upload teaser pictures directly?

Thanks in advance. 
Greetings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usergroup needs access to the user_upload folder.

If not the inline upload will not show.

Default the user_upload = fileadmin/user_upload this can be adjusted in userTS

Also make sure the user has the setting inline upload enabled.

Comment: Thanks its working with folder access. But where I can setting inline upload?

Answer (score 1):

*To improve the answer of minifranske.*

You can set a specific upload folder with TSConfig:

```
options.defaultUploadFolder
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TSconfigReference/UserTsconfig/Options/Index.html#defaultuploadfolder